# Function that allows for user input and if no input is given, roll 5 dice (supposed to be mimicking a dice roll)

Tags: javascript

I already have part of a code set up for accepting a number and rolling that many times and showing an array of results from that many rolls. I'm just not sure exactly what I should be doing for each of these points. Any advice or a little explaining of what these things might mean would be appreciate.

- check if user entered a sum to roll

  - if sum to roll was not entered, roll 5 dice
  - display the corresponding die images(I'm putting those together separately.
  - report the sum rolled in a div,
    otherwise
  - roll until you hit the sum to roll input by the user
    display the corresponding die images
  - report how many rolls it took to get the sum in a div

```js
function rollNDice(n) {
        var result = [ ];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      result.push(rollDie()); 
  }                          
  return result;               
}
console.log(rollNDice(4));
```

Comment: `if (n === undefined) n = 5;`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function rollNDice(n=5,parent) {//ns default value is 5
    var result = [ ];
    var total=0;//save total
    var images=["one.jpg","two.jpg","three.jpg","four.jpg","five.jpg","six.jpg"];//some images to display
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;//random number between 1 and 6
      total+=random;
      result.push(random); 
      if(parent) parent.innerHTML+="<img src='"+images[random-1]+"'>";
    }           
   if(parent) parent.innerHTML+=total;               
   return result;               
}
```

This can be done with another variable and parameter, and through adding a default parameter to n.

Some testcases:

```
console.log(rollNDice(4));
console.log(rollDice());
console.log(rollNDice(5,document.body);
```